# Need help with deciding on statistical test for three separate instruments

Tags: correlation, spss, scales, psychology

So I am trying to analyze my data. I used the following scales: Brief RCOPE, the Brief Multidimensional Measure of Religiousness/Spirituality (BMMRS), and the Satisfaction with Life scale (SWLS). They are all Likert type scales (1=dissatisfied, 2= slightly dissatisfied, etc.). Each measure has subscales, but I'm not sure whether I need to use the total scores for each subscale or the total score overall for each scale when I do correlations.

In SPSS, which statistical test should I use in order to find correlations between the Brief RCOPE + SWLS, and the BMMRS + SWLS (I Don't need a correlation between the Brief RCOPE and BMMRS)?

Also, should I be just summing up all of the scores for each measure or should I be using subscale scores? Because when I sum up the scores each person got on each measure, the data is all non-monotonic and I think that means I can't do some correlation tests like the Spearman's rank order. Thank you so much for any help you can provide!

additional info: all three variables are ordinal

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, adding up and averaging the scores per measure per respondent does not 'exclude you from using spearmank rank correlation test', it ENABLES you to use a real correlation test like Pearson's. This is better (more power).

I think you should average scores for each measure (scale, set them to scale in SPSS), then test for correlation (by using Pearson's) 3 seperate times (AtoB, AtoC, BtoC)

(subscales I wouldn't use seperately unless they have a seperate function in your hypotheses)
Hope this helped!